# sql query is slow when writing cache data on apache ignite cluster

Tags: java, sql, ignite

Test on apache ignite 2.7.0 and 2.3.0, if no cache data is writing, the sql query is fast, but when I writing data, the sql query becames slow, why?

And how to make sql query fast when data is writing into apache ignite cache?
Or how to seperate cache read and write on apache ignite?

Define a cache entity ABData as below and load 3000 ABDatas with Streamer.add method 10 times.
Each time after we already loaded all the ABData(suppose after 10 minutes, it means that the 3000 ABDatas have been added into the ignite cache),  run SqlFieldQuery('select * from ABData'), all the ABDatas get returned whithin 5 milliseconds.
But each time when the 3000 ABDatas is still in the loading(e.g.,each time before loading ABData, we launch another thread to query ABData with SqlFieldQuery), run SqlFieldQuery('select * from ABData'), all the ABDatas get returned after 100 milliseconds.

```
public class ABData {

    @QuerySqlField(index = true)
    private String code;

    @QuerySqlField(index = false)
    private String configData;

    @QuerySqlField(index = false)
    private Integer categoryID;

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's hard to answer without understanding of your queries or workload.

Comment: I updated the question, see if it can help you understand.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what happens here. I suggest you debug this issue, taking e.g. stack traces and trying to figure out where time is spent/where locking happens.

Then it may be some problems in your scenario, such as creating short-lived server nodes to do data streaming. They will trigger rebalancing when they come or leave.